# Migrate current JQuery/AngularJs project to Angular (4+)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm in a situation in which I have to migrate an existing project that mixes both Angular 1 and, overall, JQuery pages, into the latest versions of Angular (I guess ng5 will do the job).

Thing is, I want to perform this migration slowly: we gotta begin migrating one tiny part of the whole application to Angular, but the rest (still in AngularJS and JQuery) should work too.

How to accomplish this?

This is the current project structure:

```
Root folder
     - assets
     - css
     - js
     - demos
     - framework
     - images
     - protected
     - requirements
     - themes
```

So as you may guess, in the protected folder we've got the PHP scripts that run in the backend, and in the js folder there are the JS libraries (like JQuery and others), and as many folders as functionalities are.

Being this the situation... how should I do to begin migrating all of this to the latest Angular versions?

I'm thinking in the following solutions, but I'm not very sure if it's going to work: it would be creating an Angular project with angular-cli in the root folder and changing the backend logic static routing to its 'dist' folder, in which lays the built/compiled code.

Do you think that can work out? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you would spend more time trying to make them work all together than you would building the whole app in angular 4 without jQuery or angular 1 and roll it out when it is all tested